# How to rig a sword?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, vertex-groups

I have rigged a rapier. However, the knuckle guard of the rapier won't follow along with the blade.[image]

Comment: Just parent the guard to the blade or to the bone.

Comment: Any reason why it can't be a single object?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I managed to get the knuckle guard to move by pressing CTRL + J and assigning the vertex groups.

Comment: You don't have to join the objects to do this, but at the end of the day it works.